# How to make a nested Map from an scala List

Tags: scala, scala-collections, json4s

I have an scala List like this:

> List((List("android.*.*", "android.webkit.*", "android.webkit.WebView"),List("void setInt (int), 20", "boolean deleteCache (android.content.Context), 20")))

From the above List I need something like the following (Nested Mapping):

```
List(
    Map(
      "name" -> "android.*.*",
      "children" -> List(
          Map(
            "name" -> "android.webkit.*",
            "children" -> List(
              Map(
              "name" -> "android.webkit.WebView",
              "children" -> List(
                Map("name" -> "void setInt (int)", "value" -> 20),
                Map("name" -> "boolean deleteCache (android.content.Context)", "value" -> 20)
                )
              )
            )
          )
      )
    )
  )
```

I have tried with List "head" and "tail" along with a recursive approach. However, I didn't get the best out of it.

Any kinds of hints will be a great help for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do the "values" of `20` come from?

Comment: Are you opposed to editing your structure? `case class Package(name: String, children: List[Package])` is much easier to read than your `Map`, and ensures static type checking works.

Comment: hi @jwvh, I forgot to add it. Now, I added it to the List.

Comment: @Ethan, I want the nested Map like this. So that, I can generate some intended JSON object from this using the json4s library.

Comment: Your problem has some structure but without explanation it is just Lists with Strings. Can you describe how you get from input list to output map? Why something becomes `value` and other `children`? Why 2 separate lists become 1 nested map?